Unsuccessful build of JS8Call on Windows from source - how should I find the cause of error?
I am trying to build JS8Call from source (https://github.com/bazineta/js8call) using MSYS2 (UCRT2). The preparation steps did not generate any Makefile, so I tried cmake --build . which seems to work fine. In the final step I got error message:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/home/me/js8/hamlib-prefix/lib/libhamlib.a(network.o):(.text$is_networked+0x3c): undefined reference to `GetAdaptersAddresses'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/home/me/js8/hamlib-prefix/lib/libhamlib.a(network.o):(.text$is_networked+0x5f): undefined reference to `GetAdaptersAddresses'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/home/me/js8/hamlib-prefix/lib/libhamlib.a(network.o):(.text$is_wireless+0x26): undefined reference to `GetAdaptersAddresses'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/home/me/js8/hamlib-prefix/lib/libhamlib.a(network.o):(.text$is_wireless+0x49): undefined reference to `GetAdaptersAddresses'


From what I found by internet search this might be related to the fact that old versions of MSVCRT did not contain this function. This should not likely be the cause because UCRT64 replaces the original Microsoft library by a new or alternative one, UCRT.
I also looked into source code of network.c and found that the call to GetAdaptersAddresses is in conditional block for WIN32. I could replace it by something else, but what is it?
What can i do to fix this? It seems to be the last step in the process, preventing a successful build.
